# how to pass element of array as argument to function for it to modify, in ANSI C program?

Tags: c

I understand how to pass an array to a function and let that function update the value of the array. I'm having a tough time understanding how to pass an ELEMENT of an array to a function and have that function update that element. My guess is as below, but produces the following from `gcc: "warning: conflicting types for 'CDivide'"`.

The `main()` function defines the arrays in question, and passes them (as reference) to `fn_v1p0` as `complex_real` and `complex_imag`, where they're declared as pointers in the function definition for `fn_v1p0`. The `main()` includes prototypes for these functions, as follows.

```
void fn_v1p0(double *, double *, char *, double *, unsigned int, double *);
void CDivide(double *, double *, double, double, double, double);
```

However, the `main()` sits in one file and the other two functions sit in a different file. Only the main file includes these prototypes.

I need to perform complex division (not supported in ANSI C), which is the purpose of function `CDivide`. There's more to the `fn_v1p0` function, but I reduced it to only what's necessary to show for this question.

I've treated `complex_real[ii]` as simply a double value, hoping that if I put an & in front of it then `CDivide` could be written as shown. But my guess isn't working. Not sure what's the best way to tackle this.

```
void fn_v1p0(
    double *complex_real, double *complex_imag, 
    char *selected_form,    
    double *freq,          
    unsigned int len_freq, 
    double *Hparams)
{
    int ii = 0;
    double a0, b0;

    for (ii = 0; ii <= len_freq; ii++) {
       CDivide( &complex_real[ii], &complex_imag[ii], b0, 0, a0, freq[ii] );
    } 
}
```

where

```
void CDivide( 
    double *z_real, double *z_imag, double a, double b, double c, double d) 
{
    double divisor = c*c + d*d; 
    *z_real = (a*c + b*d) / divisor; 
    *z_imag = (b*c - a*d) / divisor; 
}
```

Comment: Do you have a function prototype for `CDivide` preceding the definition of `fn_v1p0`?

Comment: Good question Adam. I edit the question above to address this.

Comment: I think our edits crossed, you might want to take a look at my revision since I fixed a bunch of other places as well.

Comment: Thanks Mysticial, how to view your edits? (assuming they're not already in above question)

Comment: You can click on the `edited 9 mins ago` link. And you'll be able to see all the revisions. If you like my revision better, you can roll it back.

Comment: Which line of code does the warning message point to?  That message is usually indicative of a mismatch between the function prototype and the function definition—can you double-check that you have the correct prototype and definition?  The warning should also point to the line of code containing the first declaration—what does that line say?

Comment: The warning message points to the CDivide function definition (e.g. `void CDivide(` ). A second message points to the line of code inside the for loop (e.g. `CDivide( &complex_real[ii],...`) and reads: "note: previous implicit declaration of 'CDivide' was here."

Comment: The problem was the prototype for the CDivide function needs to reside in the file containing the CDivide and fn_v1p0 definitions, and not the file containing the main function. Moving the prototype for CDivide to this other file clears the error.

Comment: @ggkmath: You should post it as answer and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the prototype for the CDivide function needs to reside in the file containing the CDivide and fn_v1p0 definitions, and not the file containing the main() function. Moving the prototype for CDivide to the file containing CDivide clears the error. Thanks to Adam Rosenfield for flushing out the issue with his comments in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Take 2 functions double CDivide_real(a,b,c,d) and CDivide_imag(a,b,c,d) or pass a double-pointer-array to CDivide like CDivide(double *x[2],a,b,c,d), and then

```
for (ii = 0; ii <= len_freq; ii++) {
   double *a[]={&complex_real[ii],&complex_imag[ii]};
   CDivide( a, b0, 0, a0, freq[ii] );
}
```

and in CDivide

```
void CDivide( 
    double *x[2], double a, double b, double c, double d) 
{
    double divisor = c*c + d*d; 
    *x[0] = (a*c + b*d) / divisor; 
    *x[1] = (b*c - a*d) / divisor; 
}
```